# Merging Bit, Enum and Set fields in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, set, enums, bit

I know up to eight Bit fields are merged into one byte to save space, but what if I have a couple of Bit fields and an Enum or a Set field? Are they internally merged too? I'm asking because I'm going to have a lot of rows in my table and I want to avoid overhead as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html), `SET` fields use one byte minimum so those are out for any kind of merging.

Update: `ENUM` is out, too: They take at least one byte as well. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: Well, I guess that settles it then :) Thank you.