# MySQL BIT vs SET

Tags: mysql, types, set, bit

Does anyone know where in the MySQL literature the reference is made to merging BIT fields? I am having a hard time locating any documentation that distinguishes SET from BIT.

Comment: look to basic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: I'm not clear about exactly what you are asking. Does the [Bit-Field Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-field-values.html) and [The MySQL SET Datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html) documentation not help?

Comment: My initial question stems from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897013/merging-bit-enum-and-set-fields-in-mysql

Comment: But the second part is an attempt to distinguish BIT from SET. I may be interpreting BIT incorrectly but my current understanding is that it does the same thing as SET. The only thing I can see that distinguishes them is that SET is MySQL specific but BIT is not. I could be wrong on this but I can't find qualification anywhere. Also, BIT and SET are not mentioned as analogous on the MySQL site and while SET gets a full description in the dev section I can't locate information that unravels BIT to the same degree. I would add again that I may have misinterpreted the true workings of BIT within